# How to calculate screen Cordinates from modelview and projection matrix?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have projection, modelview and modelviewprojection matrix...My opengl object rendering also working fine with values.

Now I want to covert this to screen coordinates...How can I get the screen coordinates from this matrices ?

```
float[] modelView = target.getViewMatrix();
float[] projection = target.getProjectionMatrix();
float[] modelViewprojection = target.getModelViewProjectionMatrix();
int[] view = {0,0,(int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight};
float x = screenWidth/2, y = screenHeight/2, z = 0.01f;
float[] pos = new float[4];
GLU.gluProject(x, y, z,
        modelView, 0,
        projection, 0,view, 0,
        pos, 0);
float xpoint = convertPixelsToDp(pos[0],this);
float ypoint = convertPixelsToDp(pos[1],this);
```

I tried above code it is giving me the x and y point but they are too much fluctuating

is there any other way to get the stable x and y point on screen ?

Comment: > "I want to covert this to screen coordinates"

What do you mean by *this*, what are you precisely trying to do ?

Comment: Hi @rotoglup It means I have modelView, projection and modelViewprojection matrix and vertices...I want to get screen points (x, y position on screen) from this

Comment: Just to make sure : do you mean transform points in the model coordinate system, using your MVP matrix **to** screen coordinates in pixels ? Not sure as you seem to pass 'pixel coordinates' as input to `gluProject`.

Answer (score 0):

Your API call looks wrong.

`GLU.gluProject(x, y, z, modelView, 0, projection, 0,view, 0, pos, 0);`

Parameter order doesn't look the same as:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluProject.xml

What library are you using?

Comment: Hi...I am using the native android OpenGLES        public static int gluProject(float objX, float objY, float objZ,
            float[] model, int modelOffset, float[] project, int projectOffset,
            int[] view, int viewOffset, float[] win, int winOffset)    This is the function I am using